# python error: the parameter "pControls" must be either a Tuple or a List

Tags: python, python-2.7, xbmc

I need some help as I have got a problem with my code.

I'm trying to get the control with each id to find the controls I'm looking for then remove the controls.

When I try this:

```
def clearEPG(self):
    program_button = [elem.control for elem in self.program_buttons]

    program_id = list()
    position_X = list()
    position_Y = list()
    for elem in program_button:
        program_id.append(elem.getId())
        position_X.append(elem.getX())
        position_Y.append(elem.getY())
    program_id = map(str, program_id)
    pos_X = map(str, position_X)
    pos_Y = map(str, position_Y)

    try:
        for pos_X, pos_Y, prog_id in zip(pos_X, pos_Y, program_id):
            if int(pos_Y) == 315:
               #print type(prog_id)
               program_button = self.getControl(int(prog_id))
               #print type(program_id)
               self.removeControls(program_button)
    except RuntimeError:
        for elem in self.program_buttons:
            print program_id

            try:
                pass
                #self.removeControl(elem.control)
            except RuntimeError:
                pass
```

It show the error: **TypeError: the parameter "pControls" must be either a Tuple or a List.**

The error is highlight on this line:

```
self.removeControls(program_button)
```

Here is the list for prog_id output:

```
NOTICE: 3002
NOTICE: 3003
NOTICE: 3004
NOTICE: 3005
```

And here is the type for prog_id:

```
NOTICE: <type 'str'>
NOTICE: <type 'str'>
NOTICE: <type 'str'>
NOTICE: <type 'str'>
```

Can you please help me with what I need to do to fix the problem?

Comment: What does `self.removeControls()` looks like ?

Comment: @anmol_uppal it is using for to remove the controls. I have no idea what you mean what does `self.removeControls()` looks like. can you please explains to me what you mean by exactly?

Comment: I just intended to see the code and it's return type ?

Comment: What if you do `self.removeControls([program_button])` or `self.removeControls(program_button,)` ?

Comment: @anmol_uppal here is the type for `self.removeControls` NOTICE: <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>

Comment: @Rob what library are you using?

Comment: @PaulRooney i'm using xbmcgui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`removeControl`](http://mirrors.xbmc.org/docs/python-docs/13.0-gotham/xbmcgui.html#Window-removeControl) if you only intend to remove a single control.

```
self.removeControl(program_button)
```

You would use [`removeControls`](http://mirrors.xbmc.org/docs/python-docs/13.0-gotham/xbmcgui.html#Window-removeControls) to remove a group of controls, hence why the function expects a list or tuple.

**Edit**

One thing I find strange is that at the start of this code you do assign a list to `program_button` (bad name should probably be `program_buttons`?)

```
program_button = [elem.control for elem in self.program_buttons]
```

but later you overwrite it with a singular value

```
program_button = self.getControl(int(prog_id))
```

Which would cause the issue you see.